# Why images are not stretched in vertical size in this xaml code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this xaml code:

```
 <Grid >
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="640*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="14"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="350*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="40"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

<ListView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"                     ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" SelectionMode="Single" >
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border x:Name="border" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="0,1,0,0">
                            <Grid  Background="Transparent" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="300"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="300"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="150"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="4"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Image Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"  Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="Both">
                                    <Image.Source>                                        
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"   FontWeight="Black" TextAlignment="Center" >
                                    <TextBlock.Text >
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>
                                <Image Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"   Stretch="UniformToFill" StretchDirection="Both" >
                                    <Image.Source>
                                    </Image.Source>
                                </Image>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" FontWeight="Black" TextAlignment="Center" >
                                    <TextBlock.Text >
                                    </TextBlock.Text>
                                </TextBlock>

                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
 </Grid>
```

when I resize the window that this xaml is on it, I can see that image are resize to fill the width, but they are not resized to fill the height. If the image is too big for the height, the top of image is shown and not the bottom section.

How can I change this xaml that when width or height is changes, the image size in the list view also changes?

Answer (score 0):

See the documentation
UniformToFill preserves aspect
I think you want Fill

[Stretch Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.stretch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks. The problem with fill is that aspect ratio is not preserved (as you mentioned) What I want is to when I change the with of window, as soon as the with of image changed, its height ( the height of item in listview) changes to reflect actual height of image.

Comment: So, did you try Fill?

Comment: What about it did not work?  You know you have ListView in a fixed width column?

Comment: The images are growing when the size of listview increases, but when I decrease the size of listview, the image sizes are not decreeing.